# How to use taxonomy term as a value of get_template_part?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, get-template-part

I would like to dynamically import different template parts (hardcoded sidebars or navigations) into my layout based on a taxonomy assigned to the post. For instance, this "standard" code works as intended:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'term' ); ?>
```

and is outputting the (previously hardcoded) file "nav-term.php" where I want it to be. My question: How can I dynamically pick the term of that custom taxonomy assigned to my post and output it as a value of my function? Something like so: "( 'nav', 'dynamically_picked_term' )".

N.b. I'm selecting taxonomy terms by ACF plugin. Also the ACF API could be used.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Hello @kaiser. The question was about how to combine 2 wp core functions, custom fields & get_template_part. The use of ACF was an additional info. Edited question to make it better wp related. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get at the terms in your custom taxonomy using this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Thank you @Dan. I tried that one but I couldn't figure out how to use the function. How would you implement it?

Comment: You'd need to pass your post id and your custom taxonomy. print_r() the results and see what you get.